# Set M-values to cumulative length of line (via ArcPy)

Tags: arcpy, geometry, linear-referencing, arcgis-10.7, m-values

*ArcMap 10.7.1 — Oracle 18c EGDB — SDE.ST_GEOMETRY*

---

I have existing SDE.ST_GEOMETRY polylines that have M-values (aka 'measure values' for linear referencing purposes).

I want to update the M-values for all the lines via an ArcPy script.

In my case, the M-values of lines should be the same as the cumulative length of the line. In other words, if we look at the image below, the M-values should be the same as the length of the line at a given vertex.

[image]

---

**Question:**

Using ArcPy, is there a way to set the M-values to the cumulative length of the line?

*Note: Some of the lines have arcs. And some of the lines are multi-part.*

---

**Related:**

[Python: Working with Feature Data using ArcPy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDS04f5u1EY&t=1534s) [YouTube Video from ESRI]

Comment: Have a look at the Polyline functions at:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/classes/polyline.htm .  In particular:  `measureOnLine()` and `queryPointAndDistance()`.  Do they provide the values that you need?

Comment: For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.

Comment: Just use the [calibrate routes](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/linear-referencing/calibrate-routes.htm) tool.

Comment: @Hornbydd Good idea. If I understand correctly, the Calibrate Routes tool outputs a copy FC, it doesn't update an existing FC. Does that sound right? Any ideas how to update existing SHAPE values, without replacing the FC or replacing the records? (I suppose the Create Routes GP tool might also be worth considering.)

Comment: Yes both tools generate a new Feature Class, probably best as there would be no undo if you edit in-situ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a script seems to work:

```
import arcpy
connection = "Database Connections\my_conn.sde"
feature_class = connection + "\my_owner.my_fc"
spatial_reference = arcpy.Describe(feature_class).spatialReference

with arcpy.da.Editor(connection) as edit_session:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature_class, "SHAPE@") as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            geometry = row[0].densify("ANGLE", 10000, 0.174533)
            parts = arcpy.Array()
            for part in geometry:
                points = arcpy.Array()
                for point in part:
                    point.M = geometry.measureOnLine(point)
                    points.append(point)
                parts.append(points)
            row[0] = arcpy.Polyline(parts, spatial_reference)
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Notes:

- The script works for both singlepart and multipart features.
- The script densifies true curves -- since true curve functionality in ArcPy is limited.
- Related: [Code Review SE — Loop through polyline vertices and update coordinate](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/273763/loop-through-polyline-vertices-and-update-coordinate)